# 'method_missing': undefined local variable or method 'has_ancestry'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, method-missing, ancestry

I am following this tutorial (http://www.tweetegy.com/2013/04/create-nested-comments-in-rails-using-ancestry-gem/) on how to setup the Ancestry gem for nested comments. When I run through the tutorial on a normal rails app it works fine. My issue comes when I try to separate the commenting system out into an engine. Here are the models that I have:

**In the engine**

```
module CommentThread
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

**In the main app**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, class_name: 'CommentThread::Comment'
end
```

If I remove `has_ancestry` I can access the comments just fine. I have followed the tutorial just as I did in the first app but for some reason when I run Article.first.comments on this one I get the method missing error. Please let me know if I need to include more information for assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an engine you should put ancestry in your Gemfile and require it in `lib/<your_engine>/engine.rb file`.

**lib/your_engine/engine.rb**

```
require 'ancestry'
```

Comment: That's all I was missing. Funny how something so simple as a single line can cause such a problem. Thanks.